# My android app crashed when i press the button

Tags: android, button, crash

Im trying to make this mini game on android studio, but it keep crashing when i press any button. This is the full java code, XML, and manifest. Please any idea of what im doing wrong ?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.jkdevelopement.biggernumber;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int leftRand, rightRand;
int scoreI = 0;
String leftT, rightT;
Random r = new Random();
ImageView compare;
TextView score, leftTxt, rightTxt;
Button leftBtn, rightBtn;

public int randomNum() {
    final int min = 1;
    final int max = 13;

    int rand = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

    return rand;
}

public void compare(int x, int y) {

    if (x > y) {
        scoreI++;
        compare.setImageResource(R.drawable.bigger);
    }
    else if (x < y) {
        scoreI--;
        compare.setImageResource(R.drawable.smaller);
    }
    else if (x == y) {
        scoreI += 0;
        compare.setImageResource(R.drawable.equal);
    }

    score.setText("Score: " + String.valueOf(scoreI));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    leftTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.leftTxt);
    rightTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rightTxt);
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    compare = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compare);
    leftBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
    rightBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rightButton);


}

public void leftBtnClick(View view) {

    leftRand = randomNum();
    leftT = Integer.toString(leftRand);
    leftTxt.setText(leftRand);

    rightRand = randomNum();
    rightT = Integer.toString(rightRand);
    rightTxt.setText(rightT);

    compare(leftRand, rightRand);
}

public void rightBtnClick(View view) {

    rightRand = randomNum();
    rightT = Integer.toString(rightRand);
    rightTxt.setText(rightT);

    leftRand = randomNum();
    leftT = Integer.toString(leftRand);
    leftTxt.setText(leftRand);

    compare(rightRand, leftRand);
}

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jkdevelopement.biggernumber"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" android:background="@drawable/background">

<TextView android:text="@string/myTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textColor="#ff2233"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/myTitle" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/instruction"
    android:id="@+id/instructions"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/leftbtn"
    android:id="@+id/leftButton"
    android:onClick="leftBtnClick"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rightBtn"
    android:id="@+id/rightButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/leftButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/instructions"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/instructions"
    android:onClick="rightBtnClick"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/score"
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rightButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/leftTxt"
    android:id="@+id/leftTxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/leftButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:textSize="36sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/compare"
    android:src="@drawable/equal"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rightButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/rightTxt"
    android:id="@+id/rightTxt"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/leftTxt"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/leftTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="36sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the error output from `LogCat` please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its String Resource not found exception, because of this line,

`leftTxt.setText(leftRand);`

Change it with

`leftTxt.setText(leftT);`

You are setting Integer value to `setText()` which causing exceptions

Correct code looks like,

```
public void leftBtnClick(View view) {

    leftRand = randomNum();
    leftT = Integer.toString(leftRand);
    leftTxt.setText(leftT );

    rightRand = randomNum();
    rightT = Integer.toString(rightRand);
    rightTxt.setText(rightT);

    compare(leftRand, rightRand);
}

public void rightBtnClick(View view) {

    rightRand = randomNum();
    rightT = Integer.toString(rightRand);
    rightTxt.setText(rightT);

    leftRand = randomNum();
    leftT = Integer.toString(leftRand);
    leftTxt.setText(leftT);

    compare(rightRand, leftRand);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! i corrected the rightTxt but forgot about the leftTxt :/ it works fine now :)